# How to use settings bundle to store sensitive info in KeyChain?

Tags: ios

I want my iOS app to be configured by user. So, I use settings bundle and `NSUserDefaults`. But I also need my user to enter some sensitive information like  password, so KeyChain (`SecItemAdd` and friends) should be used.

How can I use KeyChain to secure my settings bundle preferences? I do not want to create my own settings controller, but stay with settings bundle.

What is the best approach to solve it?

Comment: You can't store data in the keychain from the standard settings app/bundle. You will need to write some code (of use a framework) in your app to access the keychain

Comment: Thank you. But how can I install my own view and controller to the "settings" pane? I want my user to configure my app from "settings" pane only.

Comment: You can't install your own code in the settings pane. You will need to collect their password in your app and save it to keychain there.